# BufferAttribute Size for IndexedBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

What should be the correct length of other (custom) attributes
if 
`length of my position attribute is m` and
`length of my index attribute is n` ?

Example, If I have a rectangular surface to draw;

```
4 points => 4*3 = length of positions is 12,
2 triangles => 2*3 = length of index attribute is 6
```

if I need color attribute (rgba) what should be the length of the array?

```
4 * 4 = 16 or 6*4 = 24 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attribute has `itemSize` property that determines how many numbers are meant for a single vector

position attribute has `itemSize == 3`

it does not matter whether your geometry is indexed as every vertex needs to have defined every attribute for itself

you can get the number of vertices with `positionAttribute.count` that is effectively `positionAttribute.array.length / positionAttribute.itemSize`

so your RGBA color attribute needs `itemSize = 4` thus it needs to have array of length `4 * positionAttribute.count`

```
var rbgaAttribute = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(4 * positionAttribute.count), 4);
```

Comment: I am aware of itemSize. My question was should a buffer attribute array have a length of itemSize * positionArray.length / 3 or itemSize * indexArray.length . But after my tests I found the answer, as you said, it should be itemSize * positionArray.length / 3